# In Visual Studio, how can I set a javascript file to "dock?" underneath an html file?

Tags: visual-studio

I am watching a video on Pluralsight about using the web app framework aurelia and noticed that he has the viewmodel (.js) file indented under the view file (.html)

How do I configure this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the project file manually, then find something on the lines of:

```xml
<Content Include="app.js" />
```

You can change that to:

```xml
<Content Include="app.js">
  <DependentUpon>app.html</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

*Note: `Content` could be `Compile` if files are to be compiled. This should not be the case for `app.js` though*

For easier manipulation, there are Visual Studio add-ins that let you do this from the GUI, like [File Nesting](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c) (I'm not associated at all with that add-in, nor I have used it... I have used others in the past though)